# Ubuntu 18.04 SFTP with users and one major user

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, chmod, chown

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 system running and want to access this system using SFTP.
I have a lot of users, that shall access /var/ftp/data/%u, additionally, I need a user f_sftp, that can access and read /var/ftp/ including all sub directories.

Current status:

- All folders and subfolders are in ownership root:root with chmod 755.
- In this status I can read all data, but I cannot upload anything.
- If I change the ownership; e.g. to root:f_user (root is member of f_user), I can't connect with any of my accounts (even though they are member of f_user).
- If I change the mode, e.g. to 777, I cannot connect via SFTP due to wrong mode or ownership.

Can someone tell me, what is the correct configuration here so that SFTP works and my users can partly read and partly read&write?

Thanks :)

Comment: sounds like `/var/ftp/data/%u` should be `%u:f_user` and chmod `2750` and the individual %u's should not be a member of f_user

Comment: Are you using the ssh chroot feature?

Comment: @Kennster: Not sure, if you mean specifically that, but I setup the home directories of my users for SFTP like that:

`Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group f_user

    ChrootDirectory /var/ftp/data/%u

    ForceCommand internal-sftp

    AllowTcpForwarding no


Match Group f_sftp

    ChrootDirectory /var/ftp

    ForceCommand internal-sftp

    AllowTcpForwarding no`